# Getting a CKEditor 4 Plugin to talk to enclosing Angular Component

Tags: javascript, angular, ckeditor, angular8, ckeditor4.x

I have **CKEditor 4** working in a simple **Angular 8** app. I would now like to customize CKEditor 4 i.e. add some custom functionality. For this I first followed the instructions at [Creating a CKEditor Plugin in 20 Lines of Code](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/plugin_sdk_sample.html) to create the sample timestamp plugin. This worked.

I would now like to know if I can *call/access/send messages* to the enclosing **Angular Component** from the `exec` method of the **CKEditor 4 Plugin**. I’m open to any ideas.

My initial attempt involves dispatching a custom event from the Plugin, and creating a `@HostListener` int 
the enclosing Angular component. My code looks like:

**app.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  textContent: String;

  @HostListener('noteevent') onEditorCommand() {
    console.log("Received Editor onEditorCommand()");
  }

}
```

**app.component.html:**

```
<div id="note_content">
  <ckeditor  id="note" name="note" [(ngModel)]="textContent" ></ckeditor>
  <br/>
<span>
  {{ textContent }}
</span>
</div>
```

Finally my **plugin.js:**

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'note', {
    icons: 'note',
    init: function( editor ) {
        console.log('Loading Note Plugin')
        editor.addCommand( 'triggerNote', {
            exec: function( editor ) {
                console.log('triggerNote Clicked: ' + editor.container);
                var divNode = editor.container.$.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
                var event = new CustomEvent('noteevent');
                divNode.dispatchEvent(event);
            }
        });

        editor.ui.addButton( 'Note', {
            label: 'Trigger Note',
            command: 'triggerNote',
            toolbar: 'insert'
        });
    }
});
```

In the `exec` method, I first try to get the `div` node that is the enclosing element of the Angular component, and I dispatch a custom event on it. I would hope this would get picked up by the Angular Component, but it does not.

I'm curious what is the problem with my solution. I'm also open to other ideas of getting the CKEditor 4 Plugin talk to Angular.

Answer (score 0):

I too needed to alert my angular component when my ckeditor button is clicked. I ended up doing it in a slightly different way than the OP. Here is my solution:

In plugins/yourPlugin/dialogs/yourPlugin.js:

```
CKEDITOR.dialog.add('myDialog', function (editor) {
  return {
    // Basic properties of the dialog window: title, minimum size.
    title: 'Add Link',
    minWidth: 400,
    minHeight: 70,

    // Dialog window content definition.
    contents: [
      {
        // Definition of the Basic Settings dialog tab (page).
        id: 'tab-basic',
        label: 'Basic Settings',

        // The tab content.
        elements: [
          {
            type: 'hbox',
            widths: ['75%', '25%'],
            children: [
              {
                type: 'text',
                align: 'left',
                id: 'url',
                label: 'URL',
                validate: CKEDITOR.dialog.validate.notEmpty('The link must have a URL.'),
                required: true,
                commit: function (data) {
                  data.url = this.getValue();
                },
              },
              {
                type: 'button',
                align: 'left',
                id: 'buttonId',
                label: 'Click me',
                title: 'My title',
                onClick: function () {
                  alert('Clicked: ' + this.id);
                  editor.fire('pageBrowser', { foo: 'bar' });
                },
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  };
});
```

Then in your angular component file:

var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );

// The "change" event is fired whenever a change is made in the editor.
editor.on( 'pageBrowser', function( evt ) {

```
console.log( 'My event data: ' + evt );
```

});